# Get ID of Table Element and open a modal with data with same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Hy, 
i have the following table with bootstrap that have data from php select:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Azioni Utente</th>
            <tr>

            <?php

                while($contatto = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultati)) {

                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" .$contatto['nome']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$contatto['cognome']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$contatto['telefono']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$contatto['email']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td> 
                    <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' data-id='".$id = $contatto['id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></button>
                    </td>";
                }

            ?>

        </table>
</div>
```

And clicking on button open me this modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="padding-top:15%; overflow-y:visible;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Modifica Dati Contatto</h4>
            </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome" value = "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Cognome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Riferimento (Eventuale)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Numero Telefono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Indirizzo E-mail">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Modifica Contatto</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content --> 
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
```

with this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            //get id
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

i want know what is the best solution to open the modal with the values ​​of sql's row with same id.
thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: You might consider linking the modal and button with classes. Id's should be unique per page.

Comment: do u have an example or internet page?

Comment: Best way to do so is `json` as NightOwlPrgmr mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an AJAX call when the button gets pressed. Something such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.btn').click(function() { 
        //get id 
        var id = $(this).data('id'); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "lookup.php", 
            data: id, 
            type: "POST", 
            cache: false, 
            dataType: "json" 
        }).done(function(response) { 
            // do error checking, etc.
            if (response) { 
                $("#myModal").modal('show'); 
            }  
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Then from here if you return any data from the database you can append them to the modal using jQuery.

Comment: and it is good this one or it need form?   
<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' data-id='".$id = $contatto['id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>

Comment: @DanceF Absolutely, was saying they need to be unique IDs for the SQL to know what data to query for; however, I'm assuming you're pulling unique IDs from the database (correct?) and therefor shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Correct, so lookup.php need to contain the select (after isset($_POST['action']) ) for give all value? Correct?

Comment: Yes, the lookup.php needs to contain the code to query the database based on that ID. However, I'm not sure if `$_POST['action']` will grab the ID being passed. What I typically do is instead of `var id = $(this).data('id');` I would do `var request = {}; request["id"] = $(this).data('id');` Then in lookup.php you can grab that value using `isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $id = $_REQUEST["id"] ? $id = null;`